# How do you access native login features through Desktop Google Chrome, like Instagram?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

[image: Chrome Login]
I am trying to figure out how to access the chrome browser's native login functionality.  If you look at the picture above, you'll see that drop down "Sign in as...".  That is not apart of the JS/HTML inside the window, that is native browser functionality.

I researched Google's Identity Platform but have not seen how this specific implementation was done.  These identities are owned by Instagram, they are not google accounts.

I've love to figure out how I can copy this behavior for my own web apps.  I am also hoping this isn't a proprietary deal between Instagram and Chrome.

Comment: I'm using google Chrome, when I click login it doesn't look like that.    Have you maybe a Chrome extension loaded.?

Comment: I thought that as well, but double checked, it doesn't seem like an extension caused it.  You can replicate the behavior by logging into Instagram on your chrome browser, then open up an incognito window pointed at a specific Instagram post, and this will pop up.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I beleive it will be basic auth - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication  but its something server side, that requests this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Navigator.credentials](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/retrieve-credentials?hl=en) API. 
Open console in Instagram and paste

```
navigator.credentials.get({
     password: true,
     federated: {
       providers: [
         'https://accounts.google.com'
       ]
     }
   })
```

you will see the same native dialog.

Comment: Great find, @ku- This feels really uncommon and only practiced by larger companies, but now I can do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome Identity API to authenticate users: the getAuthToken for users logged into their Google Account and the launchWebAuthFlow for users logged into a non-Google account. If your app uses its own server to authenticate users, you will need to use the latter.